# Duplicate each rows in Google Sheet with first column in duplicated data set empty

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, duplicates

I have a google sheet with a list of a few products and SKU

The data is as below:

```
title  |    sku    |  image  | category |  price   
prod1  |  p1-type  |  1.jpg  | cat1     |  1 USD   
prod2  |  p2-type  |  2.jpg  | cat2     |  2 USD   
prod3  |  p3-type  |  3.jpg  | cat2     |  5 USD
```

I want each row in it to be duplicated, it first column set to null and the SKU value to be appended with a `"_2"`. So the data will be as below:

```
title  |    sku    |  image  | category |  price   
prod1  |  p1-type  |  1.jpg  | cat1     |  1 USD 
       |  p1-type_2|  1.jpg  | cat1     |  1 USD   
prod2  |  p2-type  |  2.jpg  | cat2     |  2 USD   
       |  p2-type_2|  2.jpg  | cat2     |  2 USD   
prod3  |  p3-type  |  3.jpg  | cat2     |  5 USD
       |  p3-type_2|  3.jpg  | cat2     |  5 USD
```

I tried the below app script, however am not able to change the value just in duplicated rows. If I change any thing, it changes in all rows.

```
function autoDup() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = [];
  
  for(var n in data){

    if(n == 0){
      newData.push(data[n]); //Skip first row
    } else {
      
      newData.push(data[n]);     
      //set data in first column to null
      data[n][0] = "";  //This however set the value in prev row to empty aswell.
      newData.push(data[n]);      
    }
  }

 sheet.getRange(1,1,newData.length,newData[0].length).setValues(newerData);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function funkycopy() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const oA = [];
  vs.forEach(r => {
    let c = r.slice();
    c[0] = '';
    c[1] = c[1] + '_2';
    oA.push(r);
    oA.push(c);
  });
  sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1,sh.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
  sh.getRange(2,1,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
}
```

[Arrow Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Had to do the following edits, and then it worked like a charm :-), 
1.   `const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`  &  2.
   `const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');`

Comment: getActive() and getActiveSpreadsheet() are the same command.

Comment: I just rechecked, you are right. I figured out the issue was with just `ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');`. 

As my sheet name was "sheet1", just fixing that worked.  Thankyou. @cooper

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do it.

```
function fixRange(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const wSh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var oldValues = wSh.getRange("A2:E" + wSh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var newValues = [];
  
  for(var i=0;i<oldValues.length;i++){
    if(oldValues[i][0]!=''){
    newValues.push(oldValues[i]);
    newValues.push(['',oldValues[i][1] + '_2',oldValues[i][2],oldValues[i][3],oldValues[i][4]]);
    }
  
  }
  wSh.getRange(2,1,newValues.length,5).setValues(newValues);
}
```

Comment: Check the arrow notation reference in my answer.   In most array methods the first one is the element, the second is the index and the third is the original array.  But they're all explain in any good javascript reference.

Comment: @Cooper Appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: Up to the 7th row, it worked and then onwards some columns went missing. If it helps, this is the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AR0-UUnjN3rOnwUj7_SU8GrMzFWs62NXv9hdKXRrrgU/edit#gid=0

Comment: I built it to work for your 5 column example. Looks like you have more data than that.